# Pandas Dataframe - Convert time interval to continuous time series

Tags: pandas, time-series, date-range

I have an energy data with a start time and end time interval. I want to distribute the total energy to the continuous time series (dividing total energy to total hours).
As I searched the results, I have found staircase and daterange functions. However, with these results I couldn't distribute energy and sum same intervals.
Sample df;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start":["2019-01-01 00:00:00", "2019-01-01 01:00:00", "2019-01-01 02:00:00"],
    "Stop":["2019-01-01 03:00:00", "2019-01-01 02:00:00", "2019-01-01 04:00:00"],
    "TotalEnergy":[10, 5, 2],
})
```

I want to distribute each row and sum same intervals with 15Min resolution. Note that I need TotalEnergy/TotalTime.

My trials;

Staircase Code:

```
import pandas as pd
times = pd.date_range(df["Start"].min(), df["Stop"].max(), freq="15min")
import staircase as sc
stepfunction = sc.Stairs(df, start="Start", end="Stop", value="TotalEnergy")
result = stepfunction(times, include_index=True)
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Result 1:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00  10
2019-01-01 00:15:00  10
2019-01-01 00:30:00  10
2019-01-01 00:45:00  10
2019-01-01 01:00:00  15
2019-01-01 01:15:00  15
2019-01-01 01:30:00  15
2019-01-01 01:45:00  15
2019-01-01 02:00:00  12
2019-01-01 02:15:00  12
2019-01-01 02:30:00  12
2019-01-01 02:45:00  12
2019-01-01 03:00:00   2
2019-01-01 03:15:00   2
2019-01-01 03:30:00   2
2019-01-01 03:45:00   2
2019-01-01 04:00:00   0
```

New code according to Riley, the author of "Staircase"

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start":["2019-01-01 00:00:00", "2019-01-01 01:00:00", "2019-01-01 02:00:00"],
    "Stop":["2019-01-01 03:00:00", "2019-01-01 02:00:00", "2019-01-01 04:00:00"],
    "TotalEnergy":[10, 5, 2],
})

df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])
df["Stop"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Stop"]),

import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="Start", end="Stop", value="TotalEnergy")
bins = pd.date_range(df["Start"].min(), df["Stop"].max(), freq="15min")
sf.slice(pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(times)).mean()
```

Output:

```
(2019-01-01, 2019-01-01 00:15:00]             10.0
(2019-01-01 00:15:00, 2019-01-01 00:30:00]    10.0
(2019-01-01 00:30:00, 2019-01-01 00:45:00]    10.0
(2019-01-01 00:45:00, 2019-01-01 01:00:00]    10.0
(2019-01-01 01:00:00, 2019-01-01 01:15:00]    15.0
(2019-01-01 01:15:00, 2019-01-01 01:30:00]    15.0
(2019-01-01 01:30:00, 2019-01-01 01:45:00]    15.0
(2019-01-01 01:45:00, 2019-01-01 02:00:00]    15.0
(2019-01-01 02:00:00, 2019-01-01 02:15:00]    12.0
(2019-01-01 02:15:00, 2019-01-01 02:30:00]    12.0
(2019-01-01 02:30:00, 2019-01-01 02:45:00]    12.0
(2019-01-01 02:45:00, 2019-01-01 03:00:00]    12.0
(2019-01-01 03:00:00, 2019-01-01 03:15:00]     2.0
(2019-01-01 03:15:00, 2019-01-01 03:30:00]     2.0
(2019-01-01 03:30:00, 2019-01-01 03:45:00]     2.0
(2019-01-01 03:45:00, 2019-01-01 04:00:00]     2.0
```

However, this is not what I want. First energy is 10kWh, time interval is 3 hours, that means 12*15 minutes. So each bin should contain 10kWh/12bins = 0.83kWh.
The stepfunction should look like maybe;

```
stepfunction = sc.Stairs(df, start="Start", end="Stop", value="TotalEnergy"/("Stop"-"Start")
```

The desired output (calculated by hand):

```
(2019-01-01, 2019-01-01 00:15:00]             0.83
(2019-01-01 00:15:00, 2019-01-01 00:30:00]    0.83
(2019-01-01 00:30:00, 2019-01-01 00:45:00]    0.83
(2019-01-01 00:45:00, 2019-01-01 01:00:00]    0.83
(2019-01-01 01:00:00, 2019-01-01 01:15:00]    2.08
(2019-01-01 01:15:00, 2019-01-01 01:30:00]    2.08
(2019-01-01 01:30:00, 2019-01-01 01:45:00]    2.08
(2019-01-01 01:45:00, 2019-01-01 02:00:00]    2.08
(2019-01-01 02:00:00, 2019-01-01 02:15:00]    1.08
(2019-01-01 02:15:00, 2019-01-01 02:30:00]    1.08
(2019-01-01 02:30:00, 2019-01-01 02:45:00]    1.08
(2019-01-01 02:45:00, 2019-01-01 03:00:00]    1.08
(2019-01-01 03:00:00, 2019-01-01 03:15:00]    0.25
(2019-01-01 03:15:00, 2019-01-01 03:30:00]    0.25
(2019-01-01 03:30:00, 2019-01-01 03:45:00]    0.25
(2019-01-01 03:45:00, 2019-01-01 04:00:00]    0.25
```

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Comment: @Riley yes, I checked your staircase library but couldn't figure it out. it is about dividing energy equally, normal staircase (on power) works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what is needed, but if it is to essentially take the average (i.e. "distribute" as you say) the energy within 15 minute intervals then the below approach with [`staircase`](https://www.staircase.dev) can be used.

**setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start":["2019-08-27 14:52:00", "2019-03-01 10:14:05", "2019-07-31 12:54:10", "2019-06-16 10:55:57", "2019-03-07 21:21:04"],
    "Stop":["2019-08-27 17:58:19", "2019-03-01 13:13:54", "2019-07-31 13:21:45", "2019-06-16 14:35:14", "2019-03-08 07:22:59"],
    "TotalEnergy":[9.86, 9.38, 1.45, 38.77, 26.14],
})

df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])
df["Stop"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Stop"])
```

df looks like this

```
                Start                Stop  TotalEnergy
0 2019-08-27 14:52:00 2019-08-27 17:58:19         9.86
1 2019-03-01 10:14:05 2019-03-01 13:13:54         9.38
2 2019-07-31 12:54:10 2019-07-31 13:21:45         1.45
3 2019-06-16 10:55:57 2019-06-16 14:35:14        38.77
4 2019-03-07 21:21:04 2019-03-08 07:22:59        26.14
```

**solution**

create step function

```
import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="Start", end="Stop", value="TotalEnergy")
```

create 15 minute bins (a `pandas.IntervalIndex`)

```
times = pd.date_range(df["Start"].min(), df["Stop"].max(), freq="15min")
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(times)
```

slice the step function into bins and take the mean to get a `pandas.Series` indexed by the bins

```
sf.slice(bins).mean()
```

The result looks like this

```
(2019-03-01 10:14:05, 2019-03-01 10:29:05]    9.38
(2019-03-01 10:29:05, 2019-03-01 10:44:05]    9.38
(2019-03-01 10:44:05, 2019-03-01 10:59:05]    9.38
(2019-03-01 10:59:05, 2019-03-01 11:14:05]    9.38
(2019-03-01 11:14:05, 2019-03-01 11:29:05]    9.38
                                            ... 
(2019-08-27 16:29:05, 2019-08-27 16:44:05]    9.86
(2019-08-27 16:44:05, 2019-08-27 16:59:05]    9.86
(2019-08-27 16:59:05, 2019-08-27 17:14:05]    9.86
(2019-08-27 17:14:05, 2019-08-27 17:29:05]    9.86
(2019-08-27 17:29:05, 2019-08-27 17:44:05]    9.86
Length: 17214, dtype: float64
```

Note this will take a bit of computation time.  Averaging across 17214 is not a vectorised calculation unfortunately.

**updated solution**

The solution above doesn't solve the problem @ast was intending.  The solution below will.

After setup of dataframe, and conversion to timestamp etc create a column in your dataframe which represents the energy per hour rate

```
interval_hrs = (df["Stop"] - df["Start"])/pd.Timedelta("1hr")
df["TotalEnergyRate"] = df["TotalEnergy"]/interval_hrs
```

This time we'll use the value of TotalEnergyRate to create the step function

```
sf = sc.Stairs(df, start="Start", end="Stop", value="TotalEnergyRate")
```

What you have is a step function, whose value at any time will be the energy rate.  If you want to know how much energy is consumed in a particular time period then the result is an integration.  We'll slice as before, but this time call `integral`.  This gives you a Series of `pandas.Timedelta` which you can then divide through by a 1 hour timedelta to convert back from Timedeltas to achieve the answer you are after.

```
times = pd.date_range(df["Start"].min(), df["Stop"].max(), freq="15min")
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(times)
sf.slice(bins).integral()/pd.Timedelta("1hr")
```

Disclaimer (required by stackoverflow): I am the creator of the staircase package.

Comment: please check my new edit according to your answer

Comment: Thanks, your staircase functions still works (sum same intervals) even when the pd.Timedelta is scaled to 1min and times freq is 10min. It doesn't bother the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Start                Stop  Connected  Charged  TotalEnergy  MaxPower
0 2019-08-27 14:52:00 2019-08-27 17:58:19       3.11     3.10         9.86     3.342
1 2019-03-01 10:14:05 2019-03-01 13:13:54       3.00     3.00         9.38     3.440
2 2019-07-31 12:54:10 2019-07-31 13:21:45       0.46     0.46         1.45     3.160
3 2019-06-16 10:55:57 2019-06-16 14:35:14       3.65     3.65        38.77    10.813
4 2019-03-07 21:21:04 2019-03-08 07:22:59      10.03     7.15        26.14     3.884
```

Doing:

```
df['Intervals'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.Start, x.Stop, freq='15min'), axis=1)
df = df.explode('Intervals').reset_index(drop=True)
df['Values'] = df.groupby(['Start', 'Stop'])['TotalEnergy'].transform(lambda x: x.mean() / len(x))
print(df[['Intervals', 'Values']])
```

Output:

```
             Intervals    Values
0  2019-08-27 14:52:00  0.758462
1  2019-08-27 15:07:00  0.758462
2  2019-08-27 15:22:00  0.758462
3  2019-08-27 15:37:00  0.758462
4  2019-08-27 15:52:00  0.758462
..                 ...       ...
78 2019-03-08 06:21:04  0.637561
79 2019-03-08 06:36:04  0.637561
80 2019-03-08 06:51:04  0.637561
81 2019-03-08 07:06:04  0.637561
82 2019-03-08 07:21:04  0.637561

[83 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I updated the dataframe to check your result is not correct, I assume it is related with the mean() function.